# How to remove rows with a dulicated values in 2 columns but keep a specified row with a certain factor in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of over 200,000 rows but many of these are duplicated IDs with multiple entries. I want to keep just one entry from each ID. If they have any positive status (coded as a factor "positive") I want to keep just the row with the "positive" and remove the rows with the same ID that say "negative" but if they have multiple negative results I want to keep one row with a "negative" result. Something like this

| ID | gene | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001A | Gene 1 | Negative |
| 1001A | Gene 2 | Negative |
| 1001A | Gene 1 | Positive |
| 1001A | Gene 1 | Negative |
| 1002B | Gene 1 | Negative |
| 1002B | Gene 1 | Negative |
| 1002B | Gene 1 | Negative |

To this

| ID | gene | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001A | Gene 1 | Positive |
| 1001A | Gene 2 | Negative |
| 1002B | Gene 1 | Negative |

But I want this but for 26000 different IDs. Each Id has multiple entries (some have only 1 entry others have between 2-8 entries).

```
gene <- c('Gene 1', "Gene 2", "Gene 1", "Gene 1", "Gene 1", "Gene 1", "Gene 1")
status <- c("Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative")
df <- data.frame(ID, gene, status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

I am not sure I understand your criteria for selecting rows. In particular, I don't know if the gene numbers are relevant or not.

I am offering a partial solution here: I build a data frame with the totals of positives and negatives for each id, along with the set of genes for each id.

Please, let me know what information exactly you want from this data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id,  ~gene,  ~status,
  '1001A',  'Gene 1',   'Negative',
  '1001A',  'Gene 2',   'Negative',
  '1001A',  'Gene 1',   'Positive',
  '1001A',  'Gene 1',   'Negative',
  '1002B',  'Gene 1',   'Negative',
  '1002B',  'Gene 1',   'Negative',
  '1002B',  'Gene 1',   'Negative'
)
```

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, status) %>% 
  summarize(n = n(), genes = list(gene), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  filter(Positive > 0 | Negative > 1)
```